# android Make Post on slim server

Tags: android, post, slim

it's the first time for me to make a post to a server slim (without php)

I have to post the request on a link like www.myLink.com/user/ID1/value
Where id it's the user id and value is a string.

How can i make the post?

i tried with

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(" http://myLink.com/user/");  
        try {
             // Add data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", "id1"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VALUE", "The value to post"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println("return della post " + response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
```

But don't work.
i have got this error:

```
08-02 12:46:26.507: W/System.err(26293): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:  http://karaoke.eu01.aws.af.cm/endpoints.php/user/facebook-share/
08-02 12:46:26.507: W/System.err(26293):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
08-02 12:46:26.507: W/System.err(26293):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
```

hot can i make the post?

Comment: Seems like there is blank space at the beginning of your URL ? That could be the character the compiler is complaining about ?

Comment: thank's.. i'm an idiot... 
Now i have this message
return della post: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@42993db8
How i can know if the insert is right?

Comment: You should use the **getStatusLine()** function from the BasicHttpResponse that you get : http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicHttpResponse.html
Then you'll need to go for **getStatusCode()** from the StatusLine Object you get and you compare it to 200 to know if the request was successful.

Comment: the get status give me a 404 (not found?)

Comment: Can you show the content of the StatusLine ?

Comment: the message it's only 404